# groupmember option missing using dataloader

Tags: apex, soql, data-loader

Unable to get groupmember object using dataloader. Although chatter related groupobject is visible.Is that a api version issue.

Comment: Have you selected the `Show all Salesforce Objects` option?

Comment: Yes , It wasn't visible eventhough

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I had the same issue now; and found that if you click 'update' on the data loader, then you don't see group member, but if you click 'upsert', then you do see group member.

Hope that helps someone else too.

Regards